# How to distribute objects ONLY on vertex groups in geometry nodes?

Tags: vertex-groups, geometry-nodes

Thought this would be easy but have been struggling so much with this.

I have created vertex groups (indicated with red color) on a big terrain plane and now I'm trying to distribute objects *only* inside those areas. I tried adding the vertex group in the Density Attribute but it seems that it's using the weight of the group and it does not have a hard edge so the objects are leaking outside of the area.

Any ideas how to achieve this easily?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK It's the final edit. I promise

This method works in blender 2.93 Alpha(I don't know about version 2.92)

All you have to do is set the density attribute to material_index and voila your work is done, no weight paint required, it assigns density on the basis of material used.

Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like yours has a higher level of subdivision.  Vertex weights are interpolated along faces, you can see OP's plane is yellow-green all the way to the edge.

Comment: That's why I asked for the blend file

Comment: Right now it;s just guess work

Comment: Yes I think so too. I would really like to keep the geometry really simple as in the actual project I don't want to add extra geometry just to achieve this :(

Here is the blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/d21aed04db79463d992d9504ba0fd93c

Comment: I edited my answer. Read it. Hope it helps

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately increasing the geometry is not an option in the actual project file where I need to have less geometry for easier manipulation of the planes. Increasing geometry is more like damage control as there will always be overflow of objects, even if it's smaller with more geometry.

I hope there is some completely different workflow of limiting the areas using vertex groups but I'm surprised it's not more obvious.

Comment: Hey, it's me again, I gave your last comment some thought and I found an alternate solution that does not require increasing geometry. I have edited my answer for you again. Please read it

Comment: Hey Maulik! This solution is a bit hacky as I can only target that one difference between materials, but it actually works great for my needs in this project! I can confirm that it does not work on 2.92 but works great in 2.93 alpha! Hope they will add some solution in the future to easily target vertex groups but meanwhile this solution works great! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Hi, material_index is not the only attribute that you can use. I told you about it because it was the easiest to implement in your case. You can also use crease attribute, it will apply density based on the crease of the vertices or you can use  UVMap(In ur case, u will have to delete the old UV map and create a new UV map by only selecting the required faces and unwrapping it). And these are some of the many attribute you can use.